# Closed form expression for a two variable recursive relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Let $F(m,n)$ be defined recursively for non-negative integers $m$ and $n$ according to the following rules:

1. $F(0,n) = 0$ for all $n$,
2. $F(m,n) = F(n,m)$ for all $m$ and $n$, and
3. if $n\ge m$, then $F(m,n) = F(m,n-m) + \lfloor (m-1)^2/4\rfloor$.

What is a closed form expression for $F(m,n)$?

---

I've computed the first few values of $F(m,n)$, but cannot find the pattern:

$$ \begin{array} {r|r r r r r r r r r r}
m\backslash n &  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
\hline 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3\\
4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 4\\
5 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 8\\
6 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 8 & 8\\
7 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 6 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 11\\
8 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 12 & 12\\
9 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 9 & 12 & 16 & 16\\
10 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 8 & 8 & 11 & 12 & 16 & 20
\end{array}$$